# Update Values in JSON Data Type Column by given key

Tags: mysql, sql, json

My website uses mysql. Unfortunately, cuz of previous developer, there is a terrible database design and making a change in it takes a lot of time.

I want to explain what i want to do. I have table that is named content.

| id | content | category_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | { "content_de": "some german content", "content_en": ""} | 150 |
| 2 | { "content_de": "some german content 2", "content_en": ""} | 150 |

So, as you can see, content_en key is empty inside the json in the content column. I want to copy the values of content_de key into value of content_en key where category_id is 150.

The result should be like after query.

| id | content | category_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | { "content_de": "some german content", "content_en": "some german content"} | 150 |
| 2 | { "content_de": "some german content 2", "content_en": "some german content 2"} | 150 |

How can I accomplish this task?

Comment: Have you read [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html#json-paths)? Have you had a chance to try using the `JSON_EXTRACT()` and `JSON_REPLACE()`  functions it describes? If so, please [edit] your question to show us what you've tried. My sympathies on this database design.

Comment: Why are trying to copy the relative contents? Sooner, you'll need to translate them into English...

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan I know that is what we will do. But the decision makers dont want to see empty pages in English version of website until translation part is done. So i didnt want to handle this solution with copy the contents in content_de into an array with foreach loops in backend. Because the page has a lot of independent components (every component fetches data from different controller) and in order to do that i had to deal with a lot of foreach loop each components. And that would be huge cost. My options are limited due to shitty design. So i want to handle this on database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform partial update of the JSON values through use of [**`JSON_SET()`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-set) function such as

```sql
UPDATE person p
   SET content = JSON_SET(
                          content, 
                          '$.content_en', 
                          JSON_EXTRACT(content, '$.content_de')
                         )
 WHERE category_id = 150
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4df79d5358cf921afaf452963bb3121f)</kbd>

The above one works for the version `5.7` of the database too, but if the current version of your database is `8.0+`, then the following might be another option to use

```sql
UPDATE person p
  JOIN JSON_TABLE(
                 p.content,
                '$.content_de' COLUMNS (extracted_content VARCHAR(800) PATH '$')
       ) j
   SET content = JSON_SET(content, '$.content_en', extracted_content)
 WHERE category_id = 150
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found my solution. I had to use stored procedure to iteratively to update the value of keys in the rows.

Also there were so many keys (not only content_de) in the json data of content row. So i just created and declared queries for each key one by one in the while loop.

Actually, in the first, I tried to use wildcards for not applying this way.

That could be like; "Find the keys which end with _de, then replace the value of them with values of keys which end with _en". But then I have realized that would require another control mechanism like match the same keys etc.

I just solved my problem with this query.

```sql
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS updateJSONData;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE updateJSONData()
BEGIN

DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;

SET @menuID = 151;
SET i = 0;

select COUNT(id) from sayfa_icerik where menuID = @menuID and durum = 1 and lang_en = 1 INTO n;

WHILE i < n DO 

    SET @id = (select id from sayfa_icerik where menuID = @menuID and durum = 1 and lang_en = 1 LIMIT i,1);

    set @sertifika = (SELECT json_extract(icerik, '$.sertifika_de') FROM sayfa_icerik WHERE menuId = @menuID and id = @id);

    update sayfa_icerik set icerik = json_replace(icerik, '$.sertifika_en', JSON_UNQUOTE(@sertifika)) where menuId = @menuID and id = @id;

    ...


    set @video = (SELECT json_extract(icerik, '$.video_de') FROM sayfa_icerik WHERE menuId = @menuID and id = @id);

    update sayfa_icerik set icerik = json_replace(icerik, '$.video_en', JSON_UNQUOTE(@video)) where menuId = @menuID and id = @id;

 
   ...

  SET i = i + 1;

END WHILE;

END //
call updateJSONData;
```

<sub>Note: answer provided by OP on question section.</sub>